# What is a dependent texture read?

Tags: opengl, graphics

I've been reading papers on computer graphics, and every so often I come across the term "dependent texture read" or "dependent texture fetch" used in the context of querying textures in shader code. What is a dependent texture read, and what is the difference between this and a "normal" texture read?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A "dependent texture read" is when return values from one texture lookup (or other in-shader computations) are used to determine WHERE to look up from a second texture.  An important implication is that the texture coordinates (where you look up from) is not determined until the middle of execution of the shader... there's no kind of static analysis you can do on the shader (even knowing the values of all parameters) that will tell you what the coordinates will be ahead of time.  It also *strictly* orders the two texture reads and limits how much the execution order could be changed by optimizations in the driver, etc.

On older graphics cards, there used to be quite a few limitations on this kind of thing.  For example, at one point (IIRC) you could look up from multiple textures but only with a small number of distinct texture coordinates.  The hardware was actually implemented in a way that certain types of dependent texture reads were either impossible or very inefficient.

In the latest generation or two of cards, you shouldn't have to worry about this.  But you may be reading books or articles from a couple years ago when you really did have to pay close attention to such things.

Comment: Actually, according PowerVR, you do need to pay attention on some fairly recent hardware :-) http://bit.ly/yvSnM

Comment: On my GTX 570, dependent texture lookups in the fragment shader are an order of magnitude slower than independent texture lookups.  (This pushed the engine I was working on from zero/choking FPS to 20 FPS.)  I experienced a slightly-less-massive speedup removing a dependent "constant-array lookup" in the geometry shader.  (The primitive count was dependent on this value.)  Context is everything!

Answer (score 34):

The accepted answer (and the one below it) incorrectly restricts dependent texture reads to using the output of another texture read. That is incorrect.

A dependent texture read is any texture read with coordinates **that are not the exact coordinates passed into the fragment shader of a program**. Even a swizzle will cause a dependent texture read.

This is taken directly from [Apple's OpenGL ES programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html).

Comment: Thanks, @benthehutt, I clarified in my answer.

Comment: @benthehutt what is a swizzle?

Comment: @Larry Gritz I, at least, cannot see any clarification. Your answer is still misleading. One could read it and think "Oh, since I'm not using a second texture to produce my UVs, I can algorithm the hell out of them and do all kinds of crazy stuff" and then BOOM...

Comment: There is one more clarification improvement for this answer:
"that are not the exact coordinates passed into the **fragment** shader **of a** program".
You can freely do anything to your UVs in the Vertex Shader before you output them as varyings without triggering a dependent texture read.

Comment: Dependent texture reads are important because they have a performance penalty (make it difficult to anticipate what data to cache for the compute unit). From that perspective it certainly varies across hardware/drivers. Some can anticipate what data to load if the texture coordinates are modified with basic algebraic operations.

Comment: @JustinMeiners This used to be a bigger deal, but dependent texture reads no longer carry a perf penalty on any OpenGLES 3.0 capable hardware (which is pretty much everything at this point). See Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html

Comment: @benthehutt That was the point I tried to make. Even if it's still called a depdendent read, simple mathematical modifications can have no penalty. However, if you sample a texture, and use that result to sample another texture, I believe there is still a major penalty. So that should be the only subset of "dependent texture read" that's worth giving a name to.

Answer (score 10):

A normal texture read just uses the texture coordinates passed into the shader. A dependent texture read is with texture coordinates that were calculated in part using values fetched from another texture previously accessed in the shader. Thus the second texture access is "dependent" on the value fetched from the first.