# Need help drawing non-rectangle sprites using cocos2d-x

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-x

I'm having an issue trying to draw some non-rectangle sprites. For some reason the image is not mapped correctly across the triangle strip. Can anyone advise on what I might be doing wrong?  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Here's the result I'm getting:**

[image: Result]

**Here's the image I'm using:**

[image]

**Here's the code I'm using:**

```
class TestNode : public CCNode
{
public:

    CREATE_FUNC( TestNode );

    virtual bool init()
    {
        CCNode::init();

        m_texture = CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImage( "Test/test.png" );
        m_texture->retain();

        setShaderProgram( CCShaderCache::sharedShaderCache()->programForKey( kCCShader_PositionTextureColor ) );

        return true;
    }

    virtual void draw()
    {
        CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP();

        ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_PosColorTex );
        ccGLBlendFunc( CC_BLEND_SRC, CC_BLEND_DST );
        ccGLBindTexture2D( m_texture->getName() );

        static ccVertex2F   verts[4] = { {0.0f, 0.0f}, {256.0f, 0.0f}, {64.0f, 256.0f}, {192, 256.0f} };
        static ccTex2F      uvs[4] = { {0.0f, 1.0f}, {1.0f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}, {1.0f, 0.0f} };
        static ccColor4B    colors[4] = { {255, 255, 255, 255}, {255, 255, 255, 255}, {255, 255, 255, 255}, {255, 255, 255, 255} };

        glVertexAttribPointer( kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, verts );
        glVertexAttribPointer( kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, uvs );
        glVertexAttribPointer( kCCVertexAttrib_Color, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, 0, colors );

        glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)4 );
    }

protected:

    CCTexture2D*    m_texture;
};
```

==============

### Update #1:

I found this: [Perspective correct texturing of trapezoid in OpenGL ES 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242507/perspective-correct-texturing-of-trapezoid-in-opengl-es-2-0)

I created new a new shader that uses texture2DProj().  It's an improvement but still isn't exactly what I want.  I don't want the perspective effect along the vertical axis.

**Here's the new result:**

[image]