# Replace cv2.warpPerspective for big images

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I use Python OpenCV to register images, and once I've found the homography matrix `H`, I use `cv2.warpPerspective` to compute the final transformation.

However, it seems that `cv2.warpPerspective` is limited to `short` encoding for performance purposes, [see here](https://forum.opencv.org/t/about-shrt-max-in-function-cv-remap/2884). I did some tests, and indeed the limit of image dimension is 32,767 pixels; so 2^15, which makes sense with the explanation given in the other discussion.

Is there an alternative to `cv2.warpPerspective`? I already have the homography matrix, I just need to do the transformation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative to opencv warpPerspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56325847/alternative-to-opencv-warpperspective)

Comment: Thank you but no, I saw this discussion before posting.

Comment: What is the issue with the suggested approach?

Comment: I have the homography matrix, not it's decomposition into transformation. If I did, what function could do such matrix based transformation in OpenCV?

Comment: Ah I see. Well I'm not sure about the relationship between those matrices, but I assume that the transformation/application should be easily doable in numpy once you figure out what it is you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into Numpy transformations. Likely Numpy can do it.

Comment: Perhaps you can convert the homography matrix into a fractional linear equation and do the warping using cv2.remap(). I do not know the limitations of remap.

Comment: Thanks, but any idea how to make such conversion?

Comment: no need to decompose the homography. I don't know what you are talking about there. -- you can recreate warpPerspective from numpy primitives. span a grid/mgrid/... so you get a big array that contains the coordinates for every **output** pixel. **invert** your homography, then apply it to these values (and normalize/dehomogenize). now you have the **input** coordinates for every pixel. use those to sample in the input picture. try `remap` for this (also for interpolation). remap takes such xmap/ymap as you just calculated. I don't know if it'll work on arrays larger than 2^15 along a side

Comment: Can you please post a reproducible code sample? Create a synthetic large image (but not too large), define homography matrix, and apply `cv2.warpPerspective` that causes a failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at alternative libraries, there is a solution using `skimage`.

If `H` is the homography matrix, the this OpenCV code:

```
warped_img = cv2.warpPerspective(image, H, (width, height))
```

Becomes:

```
warped_imgnew = skimage.transform.warp(image, numpy(H), output_shape=(height, width)) * 255.0
```