# converting pixels to clipspace

Tags: webgl, shader, glsles

Instead of giving -1 to 1 values to my shaders, I would prefer giving them pixel values like for the 2D canvas context. So according to what I read, I did add a uniform variable which I set to the size of the canvas, and I divide.

But I must be missing something. The rendering is way too big...

```js
gl_.resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation( gl_.program , "u_resolution" );
gl.uniform4f(gl_.resolutionLocation , game.w , game.h , game.w , game.h );
```

My vertex shader :

```c
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;
uniform vec4 u_resolution;
uniform mat4 u_matrix;
varying vec3 v_texcoord;

void main() {
    vec4 zeroToOne = position / u_resolution ;
    gl_Position = u_matrix * zeroToOne ;
    v_texcoord = vec3(texcoord.xy, 1) * abs(position.x);
    v_texcoord = v_texcoord/u_resolution.xyz ;
}
```

My fragment shader :

```c
precision mediump float;
varying vec3 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform float alpha;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2DProj(tex, v_texcoord);
    gl_FragColor.rgb *= gl_FragColor.a ;
}
```

Comment: You want to map from [0, u_resolution] to [-1, 1] -> `zeroToOne.xy = 2.0*position.xy/u_resolution.xy - 1.0;`. But what does `u_matrix` do? Is it a model transformation? Is the `z` and `w` component of position even set?

Comment: u_matrix is for rotations. No, I only set x and y, but I use a vec4 position in order to get textures displayed right on trapezoids. ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56915103/why-dont-my-shaders-work-for-trapezoids-polygons/ )

Comment: Not really. I did not get to have it working, no matter what, but I gave up and I had forgotten about this question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stay in pixels with code like the code you have then you'd want to apply the conversion to clip space after you've done everything in pixels.

In other words the code would be something like

```
 rotatedPixelPosition = rotationMatrix * pixelPosition
 clipSpacePosition = (rotatedPixelPosition / resolution) * 2.0 - 1.0;
```

So in other words you'd want

```
vec4 rotatedPosition = u_matrix * position;
vec2 zeroToOne = rotatedPosition.xy / u_resolution.xy;
vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;
vec2 minusOneToPlusOne = zeroToTwo - 1.0;
vec2 clipspacePositiveYDown = minusOneToPlusOne * vec2(1, -1);
gl_Position = vec4(clipspacePositiveYDown, 0, 1);
```

If you do that and you set u_matrix to the identity then if position is in pixels you should see those positions at pixel positions. If u_matrix is strictly a rotation matrix the positions will rotate around the top left corner since rotation always happens around 0 and the conversion above puts 0 at the top left corner.

But really here's no reason to convert to from pixels to clip space by hand. You can instead convert and rotate all in the same matrix. [This article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html) covers that process. It starts with translate, rotation, scale, and converting from pixels to clip space with no matrices and converts it to something that does all of that combined using a single matrix.

Effectively

```
  matrix = scaleYByMinusMatrix *
           subtract1FromXYMatrix *
           scaleXYBy2Matrix *
           scaleXYBy1OverResolutionMatrix *
           translationInPixelSpaceMatrix *
           rotationInPixelSpaceMatrix *
           scaleInPixelSpaceMatrix;
```

And then in your shader you only need

```
gl_Position = u_matrix * vec4(position, 0, 1);
```

Those top 4 matrixes are easy to compute as a single matrix, often called an orthographic projection in which case it simplifies to

```
  matrix = projectionMatrix *
           translationInPixelSpaceMatrix *
           rotationInPixelSpaceMatrix *
           scaleInPixelSpaceMatrix;
```

There's also [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrix-stack.html) which reproduces the matrix stack from canvas2D in WebGL

Comment: Thanks. I will read these articles again to understand the matrix stuff. In the meantime I tried with your code and it kind of works, but trapezoids are broken again...

Comment: the trapezoid code will only work if the trapezoid is centered horizontally around the origin before being translated or rotated.