# How to execute multipass shaders?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am coming from the example of Gaussian separable (linear) blur shader so will form my question around it, but actually my question is more general. So in order to apply linear blur, you should make two passes first blur in X direction then in Y or vice versa. The result is equivalent to square complexity Gaussian blur shader. But here you should save the result of first pass and use it in the second pass. For this, as much as I understand, an FBO should be used to render the result of the first pass then a texture should be created from the data in FBO and again this texture should be used to make the second pass. But the GPU works highly parallel and I don't know how all I can do this not to stall the GPU. I am pretty noob in OpenGL and I can't find any tutorial for doing this correctly without sacrificing the performance.

Comment: Have you *measured* a stall? You are right in theory, but in practice it's easier to make the actual blur step to be very inefficient (f.i. by having a large, cache-incoerent texture access). I guess you shouldn't worry about it until you measure.

Comment: @peppe I am very new into all this, could you please point a tutorial that explains in depth how to perform two pass blur shader efficiently? I don't even know to measure the stall.

Comment: @Narek: Well, the key point about separable filters is, that you each stage executes massively parallel. And the stages themself are serialized. Now in case of OpenGL using an FBO and texture attachments (two different textures) is, that quite some leeway given in how the whole this is scheduled. A stall only happens if the GPU has to wait if some work subset (note the *sub*) has to complete before it can proceed with doing useful stuff. In case of separable filters each stage will complete practically at the same time in whole. That makes the whole thing quite efficient.

Comment: I've implemented one of these too.  I wouldn't worry too much about "stall".  For each pass you switch out the FBO and the shader (unless you write a shader that multiplies by a vec2 to give you an axis of blur).  And you don't perform that many passes usually so it's not a performance hit.  At least compared to not separating the filter in the first place.

Comment: *For each pass you switch out the FBO* @Robinson the problem is that one FBO texture should be generated by a shader and then it should be used for the next pass. So If you create 5 passes like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078682/is-this-a-practical-and-enough-performant-shader-for-doing-blur-on-mobile-device (see the answer) this should stall your GPU, right?

Comment: *In case of separable filters each stage will complete practically at the same time in whole.* @datenwolf how this can be if one pass needs the result of the previous pass?

Comment: @Narek: stage = pass. First the first pass completes, for all fragments in parallel. Then the second pass can execute on that result.

Comment: @datenwolf which means that my game should wait for all 10 passes to complete. which is called CPU stall?

Comment: @Narek, there is no problem here. In your application (CPU) code, you request the 10 passes to be rendered. The GPU will process them back-to-back without stalling since there are no complicated dependencies, i.e. it can immediately start the next pass once the previous is done. The render calls themselves are asynchronous, so there is no CPU stall either. The rendering results to each FBO don't have to be ready at the time that you issue the draw calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you are asking about mobile since this is tagged with OpenGLES.

You should check this [tutorial](http://prideout.net/archive/bloom/) which explains how to implement a "separated" gaussian filter with an extra (optional) trick to exploit linear filtering.

If top notch quality is not a requirement, a good technique to improve performance is to reduce the FBO dimensions by 50% when doing the first (or each) separable pass.

Ex:

- FBO "A" at 100% containing data to be blurred
- Horizontal pass, small kernel, input is "A", output is a 50% FBO "B"
- Vertical pass, small kernel, input is "B" output is a 50% FBO "C"
- your blurred data is now in "C", you can repeat the process to make it even more blurry (pingponging  "B" & "C" if you do not want more downscaling)

This technique of combining the blur pass with a downscaling gives good result & performance on mobile, but you'll have to experiment to find a good balance between number of passes / kernel size / downscaling.

On my side I prefer using small kernels, many passes and a lot of downscaling (in the context of a bloom).

And yes the GPU will have to wait for a pass to be finished in order to start another, however, from what I have seen on mobile if your kernel is small and you use downscaling this goes pretty fast.

Comment: Thank you very much Victor. It is indeed for the mobile and I will investigate your suggestions.